# PowerShell to get workflow status in a list items of the SharePoint Online

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, powershell

I need create a PowerShell code to get the status of a workflow in a list items of the SharePoint Online. It's simple in On Premise SharePoint, but in online I have serious difficulties.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize CSOM/REST API for that purpose, below is demonstrated how to consume CSOM to retrieve workflow status in PowerShell.

### How to retrieve workflow status for List Item using CSOM in PowerShell

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
   if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) {
      $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
   }
   else {
      $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   }
   return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}


 Function GetWorkflowStatus([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list,[int]$listItemId, [string]$workflowName)
 {
     $context = $list.Context
     $listItem = $list.GetItemById($listItemId)
     $context.Load($listItem.FieldValuesAsHtml)

     $workflowStatusField = $listItem.ParentList.Fields.GetByTitle($workflowName)
     $context.Load($workflowStatusField)
     $context.ExecuteQuery()

     if ($listItem.FieldValuesAsHtml[$workflowStatusField.StaticName] -ne $null)
     {
         $statusValue = $listItem.FieldValuesAsHtml[$workflowStatusField.StaticName]
         return $statusValue;
     }
     return $null
 }





$UserName = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$WebUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"
$ListTitle = "Documents"
$ListItemId = 1
$WorkflowTitle = "Approval"

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl)
$Context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$statusValue = GetWorkflowStatus -list $list -listItemId $ListItemId -workflowName $workflowTitle
$Context.Dispose()
```

Key points:

- Method `GetWorkflowStatus` demonstrates how to retrieve workflow
  status **name**

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online Management Shell is very limited to use. As you can see in the below article only few options are available to query Sharepoint online.
Unfortunately there is no cmdlets for getting workflow status or something.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-the-sharepoint-online-management-shell-HA102915057.aspx

Comment: I will try write-host $item["Workflow Column"]

Comment: I discovered get the status ID of the workflow and the ID 3 is the error ID

Comment: Now I need discover the internal name of all column of the workflows I need monitor

Comment: http://dzeee.net/sharepoint/post/2010/04/06/Workflow-status-codes-(used-for-view-filter).aspx