# See pending workflows of entire sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-administration

We have SharePoint 2013 Environment, we have some issue with workflow manager services. because of that no workflows are starting automatically on create/update.

Even if I manually start workflow on any item it will stay in **not started** state.

I am in communication with Microsoft support and they have suggested to update the workflow manager version.

before doing that I wanted to see how many workflows are pending in all sites.

Is there any way I can see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omi, here is an csom script getting the workflow execution status for all the workflows deployed to a SharePoint Site. You can edit it to check for all your sites.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-get-the-workflow-7d00eed9

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a sample PowerShell script in old thread
[PowerShell to get workflow status in a list items of the SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116691/powershell-to-get-workflow-status-in-a-list-items-of-the-sharepoint-online)

You can amend the code the loop thru all the lists/libraries in your site.

Comment: Hi, Mark, the OP's issue is in On Premise env, you are giving the online csom script